# How to use ui-state-error with jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have jQuery dialog working with my custom theme. I would like to use
the "ui-state-error" css class to show errors in a dialog with that
style. How do I incorporate that style within my own custom theme?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the class name to your class attribute for the div.

```
<div id="dialog" class="ui-state-error">
<p class="ui-state-error-text">ERROR DIALOG TEXT</p>
</div>
```

http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API

Also, you may need to add the class after you make the dialog.

```
$("#dialogID").dialog();
$("#dialogID").addClass("ui-state-error");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to paint the title you can do:

```
$( "#dialogID" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false }).parent().children(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass('ui-state-error');
```